# Migrating from Redmine to GitLab Issues

Tags: quality-assurance, user-stories

Some background first:

- My team used to work with Redmine as our ticketing system.
- My team used to work with Mercurial as version control system. We are migrating to GitLab.
- My team works with tens of different projects, each of them with a
  different repository in Mercurial (now in GitLab).
- We used to have all our tickets (or issues or stories) in Redmine. They are centralized in Redmine, and we can (and do) filter them by project, status, category, author, target version, etc.

So far we have traced the following relations between Redmine fields and Gitlab's:

1. Target Version: Milestone
2. Project: Project
3. Status: Lists in Issue Boards
4. Category: Labels

Our problem is that GitLab consider each project as a completely separate entity. We can group projects in Groups, but that's it. If we want to use Labels, we need to create the same Labels in each Project. Same thing with Lists and Boards: each project has its own Issue Board with its own Issue Lists.

How can we work with GitLab Issues as a 15-people team who works across 15+ integrated projects with separate repositories?